# What is the difference between using なる with the particles に and と

Tags: grammar, particles, verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 〜となる and 〜になる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-is-the-difference-between-%e3%80%9c%e3%81%a8%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b-and-%e3%80%9c%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b)

What is the difference between using なる with the particles に and と? When should which be used?