# Is there such a thing as: tate ni naru?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

So after reading [the answer to this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9798/769), I did some searching and came across [this website](http://shmups.system11.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8290), which said, "A very common phrase is "yoko ni naru". (Become horizontal = lay down)." So I was wondering if "tate ni naru" which would seem to be (become vertical = stand up) was used as well.

Answer (score 3):

There's already a word for getting up, namely 起きる. I think that 横になる is mostly  used to distinguish laying down from sleeping. Getting up is 起きる (and waking up is 目が覚める). In any case, 縦になる is not used.