# となる - Grammatical explanation please

Tags: grammar

can someone please explain となる ?
I read it everywhere but still don't know what it exactly means.

Here's just an example sentence:

> この世界が心つなぐ鍵となる

Comment: There is a similar question that pretty much answers this [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-is-the-difference-between-となる-and-になる).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fluent with Japanese and can't read Kanji, but I think となる means "to become" or "to change" into a final state.

This site might help give you a better explanation - [It focuses on the differences of になる and となる, but also gives it's meaning.](http://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/to-naru-ni-naru.html)

この世界が心つなぐ鍵となる - I'm sorry I can't translate this but in Romaji it would look like this > kono sekai kokoro tsunagu kagi tonaru.
Translated literally it might look like this > (kono)This (sekai)world (kokoro)heart (tsunagu)to tie, fasten or connect (kagi)key (tonaru)to change into final state.

So possibly > This world's heart is tied (or bound) to change?

Sorry can't read Japanese *yet* so hopefully this helps.

Comment: You can rephrase it as "この[世界]{せかい}が、[心]{こころ} **を** つなぐ[鍵]{かぎ}になる." 　この世界(this world) is the subject for the verb 鍵になる(to become the key), and 心(hearts) is the object for the verb つなぐ(to connect). Now it's easier to translate?

Comment: So then maybe - "This world is the key to connect the hearts of things/people forever."