# How do you say 'sentence'.

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I searched jisho and they gave me 句 and 文. Bun seems way too generic and has so many other meanings that I'm not sure people will understand it. So is 句, a one-worded syllabus which also seems to mean 'phrase'. Is there a 2 kanji word that only has the single meaning of sentence?

I'm trying to use it in this context. "I cannot string long sentences together in Japanese." or "I cannot make long sentences."

Comment: https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E6%96%87%E7%AB%A0

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/59291/5010