# use of と in 無用の長物と化した

Tags: particle-と

> 遅れて来たモテ期！しかし今の俺には無用の長物と化したそれ。
>
> My モテ期 sure has been delayed but it's here! Though, right now, this must mean i've changed from my former useless self

- speaker has gotten informed that a bunch of girls have gotten interested in him

what does と serve in this sentence, why not から？ It seems to be a bit of a stretch of be quotative.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「～と[化]{か}する」 means "change~~" "turn into~~". The と has almost the same function as 「に」 in 「～に変わる」 or 「～になる」. (For the difference of 「～になる」 and 「～となる」, see this thread: [What is the difference between 〜**と**なる and 〜**に**なる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/739/9831)

> しかし［（今の俺には）無用の長物と化した］それ

今の俺には literally means "for the current me" "for what I am now" (≂ 今の俺にとっては). 今の俺には無用の長物と化した is a relative clause modifying それ, and それ refers to （遅れて来た）モテ期. This line uses 体言止め (See: [what exactly is "体言止{たいげんど}め"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/9831)). So it's literally saying "But it (= my モテ期, which arrived late) has turned into 無用の長物 for the current me."

Answer (score 0):

Here と basically acts like に, which is to say he has become a 無用の長物. There's a very good answer regarding this already [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-is-the-difference-between-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B-and-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B).

Answer (score 0):

と in this sentence is not quotative.

If you look at 化す in  the dictionary you will see it is used with と.
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/40917/meaning/m0u/かす/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/40917/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%99/)

examples:
貴重な文化財が火災で灰と化す。
Due to fire, an important cultural artefact turns to ashes.

It can also be used with に
[https://collocation.hyogen.info/word/化す](https://collocation.hyogen.info/word/%E5%8C%96%E3%81%99)

There are many other verbs that can be used with と:
・I regard Jim as my friend. 私はジムを、友人と考えている。
・I accepted the report as trustworthy. 私はその報告を、信頼できるものと認めた。
・She announced herself to him as his mother.　その人は彼に、母親と名乗った。
http://www2.dokkyo.ac.jp/~esemi008/kenkyu/kumagai.html