# ちりと化すぞ - What is the function of particle と?

Tags: particle-と

Could someone explain to me the function of the particle と in this case?

> ちりと化すぞ

ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

「と」in this case marks what the subject is turning or changing into. For example,「死体は塵{ちり}**と**化した」would mean "the body turned to dust".

It is similar to particle に in this use, and in fact could be replaced by に. You can find an explanation of the difference between the two [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/739/9749).

Comment: I'm under the impression that 化する is typically used in reference to discrete rather than continuous change, and that therefore と化する is **much** more common than に化する. If this is correct, it might be worth mentioning it in your answer.