# Confusion with omitted particle and 祝福と変える

Tags: meaning, translation, song-lyrics

> 終わりの鐘　祝福と変える

It's from a song named HΨ=世界創造=EΨ. You see "Owari no kane shukufuku to kaeru (change)". I think it means "the end bell changes with a blessing"

There is no particle to separate it from 祝福, and then there's と.
I tried to research the uses of と and 変える's object particle, but there isn't anything that would make sense, no cause and effect, no transforming.
How am I supposed to translate this part?
No translations for the whole sentence please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very literary and stilted way of saying 祝福に変える or 祝福へと変える ("to turn (something) *into* blessing"). 終わりの鐘 is the subject/topic of the sentence. ～と変える is not common, but this type of と to mark a "resultant form/state" is found in similar expressions:

- [ちりと化すぞ - What is the function of particle と?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80519/5010)
- [use of と in 無用の長物と化した](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61934/5010)
- [What is the difference between 〜となる and 〜になる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/108/5010)
- ～と成す ("to regard as ～", "to use as ～", "to turn into ～")