# Do both と and に mean "become" here?

Tags: particle-に, particle-と

> 鋳鉄と暗灰色の石材を多用した街並みを、雪はすでに半ば以上その純白で染め、おぼろな影**と**霞ませている。音も無く激しく、無数に舞い落ちて降り積もり、街も瓦礫も、夜の闇さえ己の色**に**侵食する白魔の静かな暴虐の、魂さえ漂白するようなうつくしさ。

86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

Could you please explain the bold と and に? Do both of them indicate "become"?

Answer (score 1):

As for the と, it's probably ["と for resultant form"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93381/5010). So yes, the idea is that the snow made the 町並み turn into 影. Outside of set phrases such as 露と消える and 無用の長物と化す, this type of と is rare and highly stilted. I had to read this several times before I became almost certain about the role of this と.

As for the に, it's a destination marker (*to* or *into* in English) in a broad sense, but here it marks the resultant state (己の色 = 雪の純白) rather than a place. 純白に侵食する can be understood as something similar to 純白に染める or 純白に変える, but に in ～に浸食する usually marks a place.