# となる vs になる - Grammar

Tags: grammar, particles

There is a whole [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qb2bIAiG5lA&t=63s) describing the grammar but its in Japanese .

How would you explain the difference between:

> 彼がリーダー**と**なった

And

> 彼がリーダー**に**なった

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between 〜となる and 〜になる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-is-the-difference-between-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b-and-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression になる is mainly used to express a "natural" change, while the となる expression is used to express a change to a final stage.

First example:
彼がリーダーになった: He became a leader (naturally).
彼がリーダーとなった: He became a leader (he finally made it,  maybe struggling, maybe he had to face a lot of challenges, etc.).

Second example:
夜になったら、雨が雪になった: When the night came, rain turned into snow (If I am in a snowy area, this is naturally expected).
夜になったら、雨が雪となった: When the night came, rain turned into snow (If I am NOT in a snowy area, this might not expected).

Hope it helps.

Comment: You said になる is a natural change, then said リーダーとなった means to become a leader naturally. Seems like a contradiction. Also you  wrote the same sentence twice (夜になったら、雨が雪になった) is it on purpose ?