# What does ものになります mean?

Tags: expressions

> 「私は困っています」をそのまま逐語的に訳したものになります。

> 未使用品を買い取りしたものになります

The way my brain understands this is: “it will become a thing + the relative clause” and that’s as far as I got.

Comment: なる (become) here indicates the construction of an intangible outcome rather than a physical metamorphosis. Such use case is universal - "that'll **be** 10 bucks"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand (～した)もの and ～になります separately.

(～した)もの is a relative clause modifying もの ("thing"). It literally means "a thing/product where someone ～ed", i.e., "a thing obtained by ～ing".

- 野菜を揚げたもの
  fried vegetable (the product made by frying vegetables)
- ペットボトルをリサイクルしたもの
  a product made from recycled pet bottles

This `noun + になります` is a polite (or an "indirect") way of saying `noun + です`. In such cases, you need to forget the meaning of "become". Store clerks and waiters are typical users of this. See: [What is the difference between 〜となる and 〜になる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/108/5010)

- 彼は弟になります。
  He is my brother.
- こちらは1000円になります。
  This item costs 1000 yen.
- コーヒーになります。
  Here's the coffee.
- お手洗いはあちらになります。
  The restroom is over there.

Therefore:

> 「私は困っています」をそのまま逐語的に訳したものになります。
> It's a literally/verbatim translated version of 私は困っています.
>
> 未使用品を買い取りしたものになります。
> It's an unused item we purchased (from someone else).
> (literally: It's a thing (obtained by) buying an unused item.)

Comment: So the subject in these particular relative clauses might be an unnamed entity, generally “someone” as you put it, or it might be inferred from context, in case it is particularly important? (then it could actually be written there right?) Moreover, does “ウォッカをまぜたオレンジジュースです” follow similar pattern as these もの expressions? @naruto

Comment: @美しい孤独 The implied subject of the relative clauses in your sentences is *I/we*. It can be generic *you* or *they* depending on the context. You can say オレンジジュースにウォッカをまぜたものになります referring to the same drink.

Comment: Right, so this ものになります is mostly used for this sort of generalizing, explanatory purpose? (for lack of a better word) @naruto

Comment: @美しい孤独 This ～ものになります does not have an idiomatic meaning. It's just a politer version of ～ものです typically used in the context of introduction/guide. And this もの is just "(some)thing". It's different from ものだ as in 学生は勉強するものだ.