# Understanding ばらしたのでいい

Tags: grammar

> 「キノ達のか」
>
> 「ああ。チセの機体片が、どうしても見つからなかったらしい。代替品を探すことになるのは久しぶりだな」
>
> 「チセが作ってた飛行機の模型**ばらしたのでいい**んじゃねえか。主翼のあたりとか丁度いいだろ。……しかし、破片も見つからねえか。あんな砲撃喰らっちゃひとたまりもねえな」
>
> ファイドも長いこと今日の作戦域を探し回ってくれたのだろう。戦死者の名をアルミの墓標に葬る死神に従ううち覚えた、本来の役目にはないファイドだけの最優先探索対象。

86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

I’m not sure why ばらしたのでいい is used here. According to the context, the speakers were trying to find a piece of 機体 of their comrades (who was killed in the battlefield) in memory of their death. But they couldn’t find any. So they decided to break apart the plane model.

ばらしたのでいい appears to mean they thought it was good since the model had been broken apart. But the intended meaning is they thought it would be a good idea to break apart the plane model. Therefore I think ばらしてもいい would make sense in this context.

Or do I misunderstand something? How should I make sense of the ばらしたのでいい?

Answer (score 3):

飛行機の模型ばらした**の** is short for 飛行機の模型**を**ばらした**もの**, where もの is "thing".

- ～した(も)の can refer to an resultant product. See: [What does ものになります mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93416/5010) Here, ばらしたの refers to the parts you get after the disassembling.
- ～**で**いい means "～ will suffice/do (if not ideal)". See: [What is the difference between それでいい and それがいい here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17851/5010)

> チセが作ってた飛行機の模型ばらしたのでいいんじゃねえか。
>
> Disassembled parts of the airplane model Chise was making should suffice (as a 代替品), no?
>
> Perhaps you can take apart the airplane model Chise was making and use the parts (as a 代替品)?

**EDIT:** If I'm not mistaken, this ばらしたの is an example of **gapless relative clauses** explained in the last part of [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010). They can be used to express a (by-)product made as a result of the said action.

- 魚を焼く煙
- 蛙が水に飛び込んだ音
- キノコを焼いた料理
- 本を買ったお釣り
- 部屋の掃除をした残りの時間